# How to spend attribute symbol on Gear card?

Tags: firefly

We have this hacking rig gear card. Do we discard to use the mechanic attribute on the test? Do we just automatically get it if it's in our hand? Can we just keep stacking those cards to keep boosting our stats?

Cards include: Hacking Rig, Fancy Duds, Fake ID

[image: Ability Attribute -> Hacking Rig]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless it says to discard, no, you may keep using it.

Yes, you automatically get it if you assign it to the crew on the mission. Each crew can only hold one equipment per mission (with some exceptions for specific crew and equipment). See the main instructions for more on the rules for equipment carrying limits and how mission assignment works.

Assuming you have multiple crew to carry each of the items you're using and they're all involved in the mission at this point, yes, they skill icons stack for skill tests.

Comment: Thanks, this makes more sense - for some reason we weren't viewing it as a traditional gear card that needed to be equipped to be useful. We thought it stayed on your ship until it was needed to be used.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee LORE: Someone has to hold the hacking rig and press the buttons on it.  ;-)
But yes, pretty much everything you purchase that isn't hiring crew, is gear.

Comment: @Mufasa Or ship upgrades, which attach to your ship upgrade or engine slots.